# can´t get storefront top header elements responsive (vertically) aligned

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, storefront

Important, the site is maybe NSFW, some ebooks cover may be for adults (the site is about adults romance novels)

Hi, I am customizing my test site (WP+storefront+bookshop child theme) and I got taht nice top bar, the reaaly top one with 2 buttons and a HELP Link. Ok, with some CSS I could make those elements (a DIV with 3 SPANS containing buttons and link text) to be responsive.
If you resize the browser screen you´ll see that the buttons and text resize BUI grow vertically, they get taller.

I want to get one of these two thing made;

1- Get the text inside buttons to fit the button width so it do NOT grow in height, keeping the 2 buttons same height
2 or align the 2 buttons and the text centered, vertically, from most text (Get daily.....) top, Gift Card middle, Help text bottom.

Is this possible?

**Note**!!

The only way I could get the buttons and text Help to align vertically was with this code, BUT at some point when you resize the screen, it "breaks" ths fluid/responsive and get misaligned, then, with small screens looks nice. By aligning this element with the other 2 buttons I get "some" responsivness

```
<em>/*Align Help link*/
#help{
  display:inline-block;
    padding-left: 115px;
    padding-right: 115px;
}</em>
```

Thanks in advance

**Here the CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.site-header .site-branding img {
max-height: none !important;
max-width: none !important;
width: 182px !important;
}
}

/*Remove title from Shop page*/
.woocommerce-products-header
{display: none;}

/*Hide Pages Tite with custom Class added to PHP snippets*/
.hidetitle .entry-header { 
display:none;
}

/*Make primary Pages full width*/
body.woocommerce #primary {
    width: 100%;
}

/*Align Search Bar and make text pink*/
#woocommerce-product-search-field-0 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    color: #fe00a1; 
    border: solid 1px #fe00a1; 
}

/*Edited Cart*/
#site-header-cart{
    padding-bottom:0px;
    width:15%;
}

/*Changed cart icon bag f\290 to to cart icon f\217 */
.site-header-cart .cart-contents:after,
.storefront-handheld-footer-bar ul li.cart > a:before {
content: "\f217";
}


/*Align Help link*/
/*#help{
  display:inline-block;
    padding-left: 115px;
    padding-right: 115px;
}

/*Align Gift card*/
/*#gift-cardl{
      margin:auto;
}*/

/*JoinAngel button style*/
.JoinAngel {
    width:auto;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 15px;

}
/*Center collague image*/
.collague_image {
display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
        width:100%;
}

/*Add top padding to rectangle*/
#rectangle {
    padding:17px;
}

/*Remove Storefront footer credit*/
.site-footer .site-info {
    display: none;
}
```

**Here the HTML with the DIV containing the SPANS**

```
<div class="flex-container" style="text-align:center">  
<span style="display:inline-block; width:30%;height:35px;background-color:white">
<a href="http://sitetest.wigigx.com/product/gift-card/" target="_blank">
<button id="gift-cardl" style="margin: 30 auto">Gift Card</button></a> 
</span>
<span style="display:inline-block; width:30%;height:35px;background-color:white">        
<a id="help" href="https://sitetest.wigigx.com/contact/" target="_blank" style="margin: 30 auto">Help</a>
</span>
<span  style="display:inline-block; width:30%;height:35px;background-color:white">
<a id="Subscribe" href="https://newsletter.naughtyangelpublishing.com/" target="_blank">
<button class="subscribe_newsletter_btn" style="margin: 30 auto">Get Daily Book Bargains</button></a>
</span>  
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any idea

Answer (score 0):

I can give u an advice. Maybe u can do this with scrolling.

disable inline styles from `<span>` and add to your css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.flex-container span {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%!important;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    position: relative;
    display: flex!important;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content:center;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
}
.flex-container span {display:inline-block; width:30%; height:35px; background-color:white}
```

Or you can do this all `<span>` width 100% and like as stairs.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.flex-container span {
    width: 100%!important;
    position: relative;
    display: flex!important;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content:center;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column
}
}
.flex-container span {display:inline-block; width:30%; height:35px; background-color:white}
```

Comment: This is the right answer! the second code (stairs) fits my needs, great! Just one questions fro clarification, the first code, the scrolling, for some reason the CSS triggers an error , I searched and it seems the code and sintaxis are ok, I don´t get why it detects the code as "unknown property scroll-snap-alig", either way the scroll bar works perfect with or without that lines of code.

Comment: Hi carlos; you can look at that: https://alligator.io/css/scroll-snapping/ and https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-snappoints. It's not important. You can use with it or without it.